# ifconfig: command not found

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

I ssh into a remote machine with `root` which is installed with Fedora 18.
I typed in

```
ifconfig
```

but I got

```
ifconfig: command not found
```

and also

```
     [root@kitch proxy]# /sbin/ifconfig
     -bash: /sbin/ifconfig: No such file or directory
    [root@kitch proxy]# sudo yum provides ifconfig
    fedora/filelists_db                                                                                                          |  25 MB  00:00:04
    updates/filelists_db                                                                                                         |  12 MB  00:00:02
    net-tools-2.0-0.2.20121106git.fc18.x86_64 : Basic networking tools
    Repo        : fedora
    Matched from:
    Filename    : /sbin/ifconfig
```

then I typed in `ip link show`

```
        [root@kitch proxy]# ip link show
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:1a:a0:23:86:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and `ip addr show`

```
    t@kitch proxy]# ip addr show
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:1a:a0:23:86:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 138.96.116.9/21 brd 138.96.119.255 scope global em1
        inet6 fe80::21a:a0ff:fe23:866c/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and

```
    [root@kitch proxy]# /sbin/iptables
    iptables v1.4.16.2: no command specified
    Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

there is no `eth0` and the results are strange to me. Can anyone explain a bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Fedora and RedHat identify NICs that are embedded on the motherboard by `emN` instead of `ethN`.

EDIT: If you want to prevent uvdev from renaming eth0 to em1 check this:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.general/421412

Comment: but on many other fedora machines, they are `ethN`, why? besides, why `ifconfig` doesn't work?

Comment: The other machines, do they have embedded NICs? 

I'm not a Fedora user but try:

`sudo yum provides ifconfig`

In order to know which package installs `ifconfig` and install it.

Comment: I tried, and updated the result, how to install?

Comment: `yum install net-tools` I guess...

Comment: @misteryes, it _used_ to be called ethX until a short time back. The idea is to have _stable_ device names (if you had e.g. two eth, which one was called eth0 depended on the random(ish) order in which they finished initialization). It will be called em0, the next one em1, _always_, even if it breaks etc.

Answer (score 13):

`ifconfig` on Red Hat-esque boxes often lives in `/sbin`, which often isn't in the default path; try `/sbin/ifconfig` and see what you get.

[The manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) for `ip` is a good place to start finding out about its options, behavior, output, &c.

Comment: there is no `iptables` and `/sin/ifconfig` doesn't work

Comment: The `ip` command is slated to replace `ifconfig`, but _way_ too many fingers know `ifconfig` to be able to delete it just now...

Answer (score 8):

By default, `ifconfig` wont be there in RHEL.

```
sudo yum install net-tools
```

will instal `ifconfig` in `/usr/sbin/ifconfig`

Comment: This happens to be the most important answer here, it lets you know that you need to install net-tools; which is required unless you specific it upon OS install.